# RadGrid(Gridview) Recursive Checkbox in EditItemTemplate Column for Inserts and Updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a Checkbox inside an EditItemTemplate for an Active or Inactive status.

This checkbox only shows when the item is being updated or added as new. I have a ControlParameter for the checkbox, but since it is recursive with many of these checkboxes in the list, it throws the good old "Could not find control 'cbActive' in ControlParameter" Error.

I dont have any real CS code other than the Radgrid binding on page load.

ASPX Code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Vista" Width="500px"
    GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" AllowSorting="True" OnExportCellFormatting="RadGrid1_ExportCellFormatting"
     AllowAutomaticInserts="True"  AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True"  AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="true">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"
                    UniqueName="ID" Visible="False" ReadOnly="true">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" UniqueName="Active" ItemStyle-Width="100" Visible="false">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# GenerateBindString(Container.DataItem) %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
         </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LBCust %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] WHERE ([Site] = @Site) AND (Active=@Active OR @Active = '0') ORDER BY AccountNumber"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] ([AccountNumber], [Site], [Active]) VALUES (@AccountNumber, @Site, @Active)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] SET [AccountNumber] = @AccountNumber,  [Active] = @Active WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dd_Status" Name="Active" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AccountNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Site" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbActive" 
            PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AccountNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbActive" 
            PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took a lot of looking around but i couldnt do this without tapping into the commands via the CS. Here is my new Code for it to work:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Vista" Width="500px"
    GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" AllowSorting="True" OnExportCellFormatting="RadGrid1_ExportCellFormatting"
     AllowAutomaticInserts="True"  AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True"  AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="true" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" UniqueName="ID" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIDView" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="IDEdit" UniqueName="IDEdit" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AccountNumber" HeaderText="Sapphire Account Number" 
                SortExpression="AccountNumber" UniqueName="AccountNumberView" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="400">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Account Number" SortExpression="AccountNumber" UniqueName="AccountNumber" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtAccountNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AccountNumber") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" UniqueName="Active" ItemStyle-Width="100" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# GenerateBindString(Container.DataItem) %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Active" UniqueName="Active" ItemStyle-Width="100"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(GenerateBindString(Container.DataItem)) == true ? "Active" : "Inactive" %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
         </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LBCust %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] WHERE ([Site] = @Site) AND (Active=@Active OR @Active = '0') ORDER BY AccountNumber"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] ([AccountNumber], [Site], [Active]) VALUES (@AccountNumber, @Site, @Active)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] SET [AccountNumber] = @AccountNumber,  [Active] = @Active WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dd_Status" Name="Active" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AccountNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Site" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AccountNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="Boolean" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

CS CODE:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "PerformInsert")
    {

        GridEditFormItem gridEditFormItem = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;

        Label lblID = (Label)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("lblID");
        TextBox txtAccountNumber = (TextBox)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("txtAccountNumber");
        CheckBox cbActive = (CheckBox)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("cbActive");

        bool isActive = false;

        if (cbActive.Checked)
            isActive = true;
        else
            isActive = false;

        string SqlStr = "INSERT INTO [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] ([AccountNumber], [Site], [Active])";
        SqlStr += " VALUES ('" + txtAccountNumber.Text + "'" + ", '" + SiteName + "'" + ", '" + isActive + "')";

        SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = SqlStr;
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }


    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {

        GridEditFormItem gridEditFormItem = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;

        Label lblID = (Label)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("lblID");
        TextBox txtAccountNumber = (TextBox)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("txtAccountNumber");
        CheckBox cbActive = (CheckBox)gridEditFormItem.FindControl("cbActive");

        bool isActive = false;

        if (cbActive.Checked)
            isActive = true;
        else
            isActive = false;

        string SqlStr = "UPDATE [LBX_Portal_AccountNumbers] SET [AccountNumber] = '" + txtAccountNumber.Text;
        SqlStr += "', [Active] = '" + isActive + "'  WHERE [ID] = " + lblID.Text;

        SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = SqlStr;
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to set the value through a control parameter; what you can do though, is use an `<asp:Parameter>` instead, and set the DefaultValue property on the parameter via:

```
sqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = "X"
```

Or, with the Grids, I know with the GridView it has a collection of values that it used to perform the update with; you could add an entry representing the checkbox control, which would get pushed into the data source.  I know know if the RadGrid has the same option.

Comment: Updating the SQL will work, but it can also be done using the approach I outlined above, by converting ControlParameter to Parameter and setting the DefaultValue on the parameter.